# Equivalent to mysql regex

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-5.6

Mysql regex equivalent for this pattern:

```
<table (.+)width:(.+)px
```

I tried putting this pattern in my query but it will still hit items that doesn't have the pattern.

I use this site to check if the item hits that pattern above:
https://regex101.com/

This is my query:

```
select * from wp_posts where post_content regexp '<table (.+)width:(.+)px';
```

This is the my sample post_content that is correct:

```html
<table class="table-schedule" style="width: 737px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>営業時間</th>
<th>月</th>
<th>火</th>
<th>水</th>
<th>木</th>
<th>金</th>
<th class="holiday">土</th>
<th class="holiday">日</th>
<th class="holiday">祝</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00～19:00</td>
<td class="weekday maru">○</td>
<td class="weekday maru">休</td>
<td class="weekday maru">○</td>
<td class="weekday maru">○</td>
<td class="weekday maru">○</td>
<td class="holiday">○</td>
<td class="holiday">○</td>
<td class="holiday">○</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the other sample post_content that is wrong. That will still hit even though there's no width on the table:

```html
<table class="table-schedule">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th>営業時間</th>
 <th>月</th>
 <th>火</th>
 <th>水</th>
 <th>木</th>
 <th>金</th>
 <th class="holiday">土</th>
 <th class="holiday">日</th>
 <th class="holiday">祝</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="text-align: center;">
 <p>11:00～19:00</p>
 </td>
 <td class="weekday maru" style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td class="weekday maru" style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td class="weekday maru" style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td class="weekday maru" style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td class="weekday maru" style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td class="holiday" style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td class="holiday" style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td class="holiday" style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="text-align: center;">
 <p>11:00～17:00</p>
 </td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">○</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">休</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Note: mysql version 5.6

Comment: That regexp should work fine in MySQL.

Comment: Is there a width anywhere in the post content for those that you don't want to match? I'd think you would want to allow any character except closing HTML tags in your regex to make sure the width is an attribute on the table element - `<table ([^>]*)width:([^>]+)px`

Comment: It works for me here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMB8Vufv66SLGjQmmrbjf2/1 I had to remove all the non-ASCII characters because I couldn't figure out how to get DB fiddle to accept them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your current regex pattern is valid, it won't behave the way you want, because the `(.+)` terms might match across tags.  Try this version:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content REGEXP '<table [^>]+width: [0-9]+px';
```

### Demo

Comment: His problem is that it's matching rows that don't have `width` in them at all. So while this is a valid improvement, it doesn't seem related to the problem.

Comment: Then our understandings of the problem differ.

Comment: He wrote **That will still hit even though there's no width on the table:**. Look at the second example.

Comment: @Barmar MySQL's `REGEXP` [appears to operate in DOT ALL mode by default](https://rextester.com/DAAEIG60643).

Comment: Looks like they've fixed that in 8.0, you need to use the `(?m)` modifier.

Comment: But it still doesn't explain why the second example is matching, since it doesn't have `width` anywhere. Unless he's posted an incorrect example.

Comment: @Barmar I get your point now.  I was assuming that downstream in the second text there was a stray `width=` attribute, _not_ part of the `<table>` tag itself.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Or maybe you're right, and he simplified the examples too much.

Comment: And certainly it's possible that there are other cases in his table where this fix is necessary, if not the one he showed.